# How can i override checkstyle comment line width checking of 80?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Checkstyle checks that comments are not longer than 80 characters long.

How do i override this limitation and give it another value, i.e. 140?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<module name="LineLength">
    <property name="max" value="140"/>
</module>
```

should take care of `comments` as well

Comment: Thanks tolitius, which file may i place this in?

Comment: sure. you would usually have a `checkstyle.xml` config file ( that you can also provide as a command line parameter ) see docs [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html). If you use any checkstyle plugins ( e.g. Eclipse ), you can see which file it points to. Here is an [example](http://programmers-blog.com/2008/05/04/a-reasonable-checkstyle-xml) of this config file.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i made a small writeup on this too. http://java.sg/allow-project-specific-settings-in-checkstyle-plugin/